# jQuery not working well on Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I created a web page and the JavaScript code is working perfectly on Chrome. But when I tested it on Firefox and IE, it has lots of bugs. I just don't understand why my DOM elements are not being affected when I try to change their html or text with jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2>Game</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h2>Score: <span id="count">0</span></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="tablediv" class="col-md-12">
                    <table id="table" style="empty-cells:show;table-layout:fixed;"></table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 id="message"></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The script:

```
if($('#' + i + j).html() == x) {

            $('#count').text(parseInt($('#count').text()) + 1);

            if(parseInt($('#count').text()) == 20) {

                clearInterval(interval);
                $('#message').text("You won!");

            }

        }
```

This is just the part of the code where I try to add 1 to the #count element text. It works fine on Chrome. But it won't add 1 on Firefox or IE. It's weird.

Comment: `it has lots of bugs` - share them ... I think you need to wrap your code in jQueery's pretty much used everywhere `document ready` pattern

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see how you're calling that code.

Comment: What are `i` and `j` and `x`? What *does* happen in FF and IE? Do you get any errors in the console, or...?

Comment: Yes, please provide all of your code. If possible create a jsfiddle or codepen and post the link.